# Reliable method to check actual size occupied by data in hot cache

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a table with 1 day of hot cache policy on it. And with that assume that cache utilization of the ADX cluster is less than 80%. Considering that, what would be a reliable method to exactly know the amount of cache space (TB) actually occupied by the table? I came up with the following two methods but they both return significantly different numbers:-

```
.show table <TableName> extents hot | summarize sum(ExtentSize)/pow(1024,4)
.show table <TableName> extents | where MaxCreatedOn >= ago(1d) | summarize extent_size=sum(ExtentSize) | project size_in_TB=((extent_size)/pow(1024,4))
```

The second command returns count more than 10 times higher than the first one. How can it be that different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both commands you ran should result with the same value, assuming:

1. you ran them at the same time (or quickly one after the other)
2. the *effective* caching policy is indeed 1 day (have you verified that is indeed the case?)

Regardless - the most efficient way to get that data point is by using the following command:

```
.show table TABLENAME details
| project HotExtentSizeTb = HotExtentSize/exp2(40), CachingPolicy
```

Here's an example from a table of mine, which has a caching policy of 4 days (set at table level), and a retention policy with a soft delete period of 3650 days:

```
// option 1
// --------
.show table yonis_table extents hot
| summarize HotExtentSizeTb = sum(ExtentSize)/exp2(40)

  // returns: HotExtentSizeTb: 0.723723856871402   <---

// option 2: least efficient
// -------------------------
.show table yonis_table extents
| where MaxCreatedOn >= ago(4d)
| summarize HotExtentSizeTb = sum(ExtentSize)/exp2(40)

  // returns: HotExtentSizeTb: 0.723723856871402   <---

// option 3: most efficient
// ------------------------
.show table yonis_table details
| project HotExtentSizeTb = HotExtentSize/exp2(40), CachingPolicy, RetentionPolicy

   // returns: 
   HotExtentSizeTb: 0.723723856871402,             <---
   CachingPolicy: {
     "DataHotSpan": "4.00:00:00"
   },
   RetentionPolicy: {
     "SoftDeletePeriod": "3650.00:00:00",
     "Recoverability": "Enabled"
   }
```